# trouble using media query to switch divs with background images from columns to rows

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I am a first-time coder. I am trying to design a prototype gallery and comics nav page that will switch divs from columns to rows depending on the screen size. I attempted to do this with a media query. The divs appear to change all right, but I do not know why they lose their background images in the process.

Everything CSS-related works just like I want it to before the media query kicks in, whether I design it columns-first or rows-first. Once I resize the browser to get the alternate view the images disappear. If anyone can explain why this is happening, and/or suggest a better route, I would be -extremely- grateful.

Pictures, because I don't have a live site yet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyc0p.jpg

Code from the desktop to mobile site, if it will help at all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Desktop to Mobile</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background-color: rgba(0,153,153,1);
      }
      body,td,th {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
      }
      #apDiv1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/1.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/2.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv3 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 3;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/3.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv4 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 75%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 4;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/4.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv5 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 175%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/4.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv6 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 6;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/1.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv7 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 125%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 7;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/2.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
      #apDiv8 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150%;
        top: 0px;
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 8;
        background-image: url(_ImagesMain/3.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Mobile -->
    <link href="_CSS/Mobile_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:800px)">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="apDiv1">Comics</div>
    <div id="apDiv2">Gallery</div>
    <div id="apDiv3">Forum</div>
    <div id="apDiv4">Store</div>
    <div id="apDiv5">Blog</div>
    <div id="apDiv6">Patreon</div>
    <div id="apDiv7">Commission</div>
    <div id="apDiv8">Links</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Mobile_CSS.css Referred to:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#apDiv1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 3;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 4;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 175%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 9;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 6;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 125%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 7;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
#apDiv8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  z-index: 8;
  background-image: url(_ImagesMain/3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This is what I get when I run your code: https://jsfiddle.net/fbmgjtk9/
It doesn't look like anything, please fix your code so I can try and help you better.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` means that the website will be responsive, adapt itself to device screen (viewport) width

Comment: Excellent job providing some code and stating your question! You asked if anyone could suggest a better route so here is just an idea. Have you thought of using bootstrap. Creating different layouts for different screens is really simple, and it is a really good skill to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! All I had to do was disable the background-image properties on the referred-to Mobile_CSS.css.

Guess html or css didn't like the redundancy? idk. Feel free to comment, I'd still appreciate an explanation if anyone had it.